# WF4 Activity Designer Culture

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, culture, activitydesigner

I'm currently developping a solution using workflow foundation 4 i have a WPF Host Application and an Activity Library containing my different activities.
No one of the two projects is referencing the other, so i'm simply loading my activities in runtime from the resulting DLL of the Activity Library.

To make my solution multilanguage, i'm using two resources files in my wpf application and that works perfectly, but when i came to do the same thing with the activities' designers, i didn't knew how, even after googling. I created a resource folder with 3 resources files like : Resources.resx, Resources.en.resx and Resources.fr-Fr.resx: In my activity designer i'm referencing the resources folder and i'm defining Labels' content this way: 
     Content="{x:Static resx:Resource.UserStepTitle}"
I have no errors, it looks like working fine, but in runtime the label is just Empty.
Please note also that the Culture is defined in the host application, in the App.xaml.cs :
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-Fr");
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-Fr");

Can someone help please ? and thanks.

Comment: Are you using WF designer re-hosting? If so are you creating the design surface in a separate app domain as most of the documentation suggests you should?

Comment: Yes, i'm rehosting the workflow designer in my wpf application.

And i'm not creating the designer surface in a separate app-domain, but i don't see the impact of that on my Culture problem.

Comment: @Ouss if you were the separate app domain might have difficultly accessing your different resource files. As your setting the culture in the calling application can you retry setting it in the activity designers as well?

Comment: @DotNetHitMan : I gave it a try, it is always showing an empty label.
I tried defining the culture in the constructor of my activity designer, before and after initializing components : In visual studio, it shows the correct value from the resource file, but in runtime nothing